# CGA Output from GERT666 (or other GPIO connection)

Tags: output

I have a monitor which accepts 4-bit TTL CGA Only. Does anyone know if there is a way to *directly* output 4-bit TTL from the Raspberry Pi?

I know that there exists VGA-CGA converters, but it would be quite difficult to implement in the intended setup. I am looking for a way to output CGA *directly* from the Pi.

Thanks,

Comment: Might want to try the Raspberry Pi Forums - as Gert keeps an eye on there.